# OpenCV portability

Tags: c, opencv, portability, dev-c++

I created an algorithm in C, using `Dev C++ 4.9.9.2` and `OpenCV 2.1` in Windows XP SP3, and I need a solution to run the executable in other computers, without opencv's installation. Just copying the file `cv210.dll` will solve this issue?

Thanks and sorry about the English.

Answer (score 1):

copying the dlls will work, but you probably need more than cv210.dll, like higgui and imgproc.

look at the headers your program is using, and at the libs you're linking against.
for each .lib you'll need the corresponding dll.

tools like "dependency walker" are quite helpful too.